# c# cannot cast object to interface in a method with multiple generic parameters

Tags: c#, generics, casting

I'm playing with Generics and in a method with two generic parameters try to cast an object to interface, which doesn't work. The below code demonstrates problem:

```
    private void GenericMethod<T, U>() 
        where T : Block
        where U : IBlock
    {
        var list = new List<T>();

        // this casting works
        var item = new Block();
        var iItem = (IBlock)item;

        foreach (var l in list)
        { 
            // this doesn't compile
            var variable = (U)l;
        }
    }
```

Here Block is a class and IBlock is interface implemented by this class.

Why does casting (U)l fail? How can I do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If T inherits from Block, and U from IBlock it does not mean T will inherit from U even if Block inherits from IBlock. For example:

```
public class TBlock : Block
{
   public void NewMethod() {}
}

public interface UIBlock : IBlock
{
   void AnotherNewMethod();
}
```

To make this example work, you'd have to change

```
where T : Block
where U : IBlock
```

to

```
where U : IBlock
where T : Block, U
```

to make sure T inherits from U.

Answer (score 2):

While you can convert T to IBlock, you can't know if it will be convertible to U, as far as the rules are - U implements IBLock but can be any type.

Comment: To be pedantic: U implements IBlock but can be any *type*, not necessarily a class.

Answer (score 2):

You can cast your iterator. 
https://dotnetfiddle.net/FgKdL8

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
    }

    private void GenericMethod<T, U>() 
        where T : Block
        where U : IBlock
    {
        var list = new List<U>();

        // this casting works
        var item = new Block();
        var iItem = (IBlock)item;

        // cast your iterator
        foreach (U l in list)
        { 

        }
    }

    public interface IBlock
    {}
    public class Block : IBlock
    {}
}
```

Comment: Hehe, resolving the problem by deleting the offending code line, ehh...?

Comment: Yes, you did delete the code line that is relevant to the question: `var variable = (U)l;`.

Comment: That line is deleted because you no longer need it. Instead of using the var variable = (U)l; you can directly use the iterator l.

Comment: Oops, okay. I stand corrected. Didn't see that you explicitly made `l` a variable of type `IBlock` ... easy to miss ... :)

Comment: @Believe2014 It still doesn't solve the problem... `l` still isn't `U`.

Comment: But the author wanted U, which is IBlock.  var variable = (U)l;

Comment: @ahruss, it should not matter since within the generic method you can access only such members of U which are implemented by `IBlock`.

Comment: ultimately, I like the answer by @James Curran

Comment: IBlock works but it is indeed not what I wanted. It should have been foreach (U l in list) but this doesn't compile either.

Comment: I have edited my answer to use List<U>. I just want to point out that you can cast the iterator instead of just using var.

Answer (score 0):

If you can guarantee that T will inherit U, you can add that constraint to the declaration:

```
where U : IBlock where T : Block, U
```

If you want the function to still work either way, but cast to U if possible (I can't really imagine why you'd want this, but...), you can do this:

```
public GenericMethod<T, U>()
    where T : Block
    where U : class, IBlock // must be a class to use the `as` operator 
{
    // ... 
    var variable = item as U;
}
```

Comment: If you CANNOT guarantee that T will inherit U, it will fail, period. Also, we can't use `class` as the OP has told us that U is an interface, but then, I see no reason why we can't use `as` with an interface.